# KVM Host with 88 physical cores uses only 14 on 64 core Guest

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, vcpu

I do have a server with 2 CPUs (22 Cores each plus HT). I created a KVM Guest with 64 allocated cores. When I run a compilation task the virtual machine shows all 64 cores at 100% (at moderate Disk I/O and memory usage) but on the physical machine the guest only uses 14 cores at 100% instead of all the 88 cores randomly (or 64 dedicated cores at 100%). Even if I spawn more compilation tasks this doesn't change. Is there any parameter or setting I have to change to actually use all the computing power that is available?

[image: EDIT: screenshot of htop (left guest, right host)]

Comment: How do you create your KVM Guest? CLI? GUI?

Comment: I used an XML-Dump in virsh because it was a migration from an older server and changed configuration to match the new server in virt-manager.

Comment: Could you show the output of `virsh cpu-stats <VMname>`?

Comment: All cores except of the 14 show 0.0000s. But I could find at least one error. There was a vCPU pinning in the XML which doesn't appear in virt-manager -.- I removed it via `for i in {0..63}; do sudo virsh vcpupin $kvmdomain $i r --config; done` and restarted the guest. Unfortunately it still uses only the 14 cores. I will reboot the host to see if it still happens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There was a vCPU pinning in the XML which doesn't appear in virt-manager -.- I removed it via

```
for i in {0..63}; do sudo virsh vcpupin $kvmdomain $i r --config; done
```

and removed the line in the XML-file via

```
sudo virsh edit <domain>
```

After that I restarted the guest.

Comment: And now it works, yes?

Comment: Until the comment by @Lenniey has been handled, this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Lenniey yes, now it works as intended

Comment: so what do you see now? How many physical cores used?